# string format for 13 digit unix in ATHENA

Tags: sql, string, datetime, amazon-athena, presto

I am using SQL in ATHENA and i have timestamps like this: 1634009513663. I guess it's UNIX up to milliseconds?
I am trying to convert it into datetime format but I run into an error. I guess it's the string format I've passed:

```
SELECT date_parse(to_iso8601(from_unixtime(cast(timestamp as double))),'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "53736-04-13T06:40:59.000Z" is malformed at "6-04-13T06:40:59.000Z"
```

Comment: Please see the update - you can simplify query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse unix timestamp to millisecond you can handle milliseconds manually:

```sql
WITH dataset(udt) AS (
    values (1634009513663)
)

SELECT date_add('millisecond', udt % 1000, from_unixtime(udt/1000))
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2021-10-12 03:31:53.663 |

**UPD**

As [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109/theo) suggested `from_unixtime` can handle floating point values, so you can simplify everything using `from_unixtime(udt/1000.0)`:

```sql
SELECT from_unixtime(udt/1000.0)
FROM dataset
```

Comment: You can simplify this to just `from_unixtime(udt/1000.0)` (divide by a float instead of an int)